# File size 0 bytes when downloading remote image using PHP and Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I am currently trying to download multiple image resources from a remote GraphQL API using PHP and Guzzle. At current, I am downloading the images and storing them to my web server but all of the files have 0 bytes and I can't figure out why as I have a status code of 200 for each request.

Currently, my code is:

```
foreach ($images as $url) {
  $client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://removed.co.uk/api/graphql',
    'auth' => [
      'removed',
      'removed',
    ],
  ]);

  $request = $client->request('GET', '/resources/image/'. basename($url) .'', ['sink' => 'api_files/product_images/'. basename($url) .'']);
  echo $request->getStatusCode() . '<br />';
}
```

The array $images contains the absolute path for each image which I am trying to download and store on the web server. In principle this code is working and I can see the files within the api_files/product_images/ directory but all of them are 0 bytes in size.

What am I missing?

Comment: What else, besides the status code, does the response contain?

Comment: When I print_r $request I get a large output but nothing really seems relevant to the image resource. I can add a pastebin URL for the output?

Comment: Can you post the response headers?